# where is after_update called twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

My model `Projelement` has these callbacks:

```
after_create   { |p| p.log_activity "created" }
after_update   { |p| p.log_activity "updated" }
```

And `Projelement.log_activity` looks like:

```
# create new Activity object
# point it to the project & projelement
@a = Activity.new
@a.projelement = self
@a.project = self.project

# record the type of activity
case op_type
when "created"
  @a.operation = "created"
when "deleted"
  @a.operation = "deleted"
when "updated"
  @a.operation = "updated"
end

@a.save
```

So when a `Projelement` is created, all's good:

- One `Activity` record of `created` type

But when a `Projelement` is updated, then I get:

- Two duplicate `Activity` records of `updated` type
- Same timestamps

Can `after_update` callback be called twice somewhere?

p.s. when a `Projelement` is saved, it looks something like this (a `Milestone` is a `Projelement`):

```
def update    
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @milestone.update_attributes(params[:milestone])

    # flag that current_user has this milestone
    @milestone.read_by.clear
    @milestone.read_by << current_user
    @milestone.save

    ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Dumb question: are you saving the Projelement twice ? what does the update code look like?

Comment: Dumb initial post: sorry, I forgot to post the update code. Hmm, I thought I wasn't saving twice (looking at this for a long time). But pasting the code ... I seem to call ``update_attributes`` and then ``save``?

Comment: Posting this as a comment because you really answered your own question. Yeah, it's because you're calling [`update_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L192) (which internally calls `save`) and then you're calling `save` again yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys: sometimes just "talking it out loud" helps with seeing what's in front of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @frederick-cheung and @pjumble:

In the `update` method, where `Projelement` instance is being updated:

- `update_attributes` is being called
- Then `save` is called

so the `after_update` callback is initiated twice per `Projelement`