# Combining save so after_update is only called once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, callback, save

I found that my `Projelement`'s `after_update` callback was triggering twice, because I was saving a `Projelement` twice ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960180/where-is-after-update-called-twice#comment12721470_9960180)):

```
def update    
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @milestone.update_attributes(params[:milestone])

      # flag that current_user has this milestone
      @milestone.read_by.clear
      @milestone.read_by << current_user
      @milestone.save

    ...
    end
  end
end
```

So I'm trying to do two things:

1. Save and validate a `Projelement`'s attributes
2. Mark the `Projelement` to flag that the current user has read it

Separating them out creates two `after_update` callback invocations, which is not what I want.

What's the best way to make it so that `after_update` is only triggered once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to do a single save/update AND letting the model worry about assigning the read_by, in this way:

#### Controller code

```
@milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])
@milestone.attributes = params[:milestone]
@milestone.set_read_by(current_user) 

# the .save will be the only db transaction
if @milestone.save 
  #... 
else 
  #...
end
```

#### milstone.rb (model) code

```
def set_read_by(user)
  read_by.clear
  read_by << user
end
```